# Are C and C++ function pointers compatible?

Tags: c++, c

Are pointers to (non-member) C++ functions compatible between C++ and C ?

Given e.g. C code that does

```
void  doit(void (*cb)(int i))
{
     cb(100);
}
```

Can the do_it function (which would have C linkage) be called from C++ code
with a C++ function pointer e.g.:

```
namespace {
  void my_function(int i) {
    //...
  }
  void other_function() { 
      doit(my_function);
  }
};
```

where my_function is a non-member function, or a static member function ?
I suppose this must mean the calling convention is the same for C and C++ code for that to work
- is that guaranteed ?

Or does the C++ code need C linkage to the function passed as a pointer to `doit`, 
e.g.

```
namespace {
  extern "C" {
  void my_function(int i) {
    //...
  }
  }
  void other_function() { 
      doit(my_function);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware (and for common types of processor architectures), as long as the function is a "free function" or "static member function", it will have the same calling convention in C++ and C. It is only naming convention that changes with that type of function. When you pass a function as a parameter to the another function, it is not using the name of the function (beyond the immediate compilation, that is) to determine which function it is - it's just an address of a function at that point.

So it should be perfectly fine to do your first option.

Comment: Whether a function is `extern "C"` or not is part of its type.  A C++ compiler must issue a diagnostic if you try to assign an `extern "C++"` function to an `extern "C"` pointer.  A couple of widespread compilers fail to be compliant in this regard, but better compilers will issue a diagnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the function must have `extern "C"` linkage in order to be passed as a pointer to a function expecting a C-linkage function pointer. With that said, the compilers I've worked with have no problem accepting global functions and static member functions without explicit C linkage.

Note, however, that `extern "C"` also disables name mangling. This means that notwithstanding your anonymous namespace, if you do explicitly specify `extern "C"`, a function named `my_function` in a different translation unit may lead to a multiply defined symbol when linking.

Comment: `extern "C"` doesn't usually disable name mangling; it replaces C++ mangling with C mangling, which typically prepends an underscore to the name. More generally, `extern "C"` tells the compiler to do whatever is needed to make the function callable from C.

Answer (score -1):

You can if it isn't a class function of course.
Else you need to specifiy the classname in your pointer name.